# NSNotificationCenter remove observer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Why do we need to call removeobserver explicitly in dealloc?

Why can't the runtime able to detect that an instance is dealloced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time that NSNotificationCenter was originally implemented, there was no such thing as auto-zeroing weak references in Objective-C (this came with ARC). It would be possible to implement pub-sub using weak references, but they haven't changed the API/behavior for whatever reason.